# Tool to measure "screen flickering level"

Tags: display, software-rec

I have an LCD monitor (BENQ FP931) which started to flicker recently. Sometimes I can recognize the flickering, and sometimes I cannot.

I need a tool (preferably a free one) to test the monitor's flickering action. It would be nice if it could give some technical details (e.g. the level of flickering, change of this level over time, etc.).

Note: 
For those who may want to know about the problem: There is no problem with the PC and the monitor cables; I have tested them. The flickering problem definitely comes from the monitor (its production date is Nov. 2004).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem is most likely with the monitor and not the pc you'll have to use some external device to measure it since the pc isn't aware of any flickering.

Is it a desktop or a laptop? If it is a laptop you should try to see if the flickering disappears when you unplug the laptop en let it run on battery power.

Comment: It's connected to a laptop at the moment. Flickering continues on the battery power as well.

Comment: I thought there would be a tool to make PC aware of the flickering and test it.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to make the pc aware of it. It just sends the signals to the monitor and doesn't receive any information about the quality of the screen or even if it is working or not.